# Android - SQL Insert Manually

Tags: java, android, sql, database, intellij-idea

I am currently working on an android quiz application with the questions linking to the database, however, I was be able to create the database created but somehow the values such as list of questions won't be inserted manually. As I have opened the database, it has organized the columns I have wanted but no values will be display such as the 'example question' Have I been missing some line of code?

Many Thanks

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Questions.db";
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Questions";
   public static final String QUESTION_NUMBER = "Question_Number";
   public static final String QUESTION = "Question";
   public static final String ANSWER_ONE = "Answer_ONE";
   public static final String ANSWER_TWO = "Answer_THREE";
   public static final String ANSWER_THREE = "Answer_FOUR";

   private SQLiteDatabase db;



   public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
   {
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
   {
      this.db = db;
      final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            QUESTION_NUMBER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
            ANSWER_ONE + " TEXT, " +
            ANSWER_TWO + " TEXT, " +
            ANSWER_THREE + " TEXT " +
            ")";

      db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
      fillQuestionTable();


   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1)
   {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);
      onCreate(db);
   }

   private void fillQuestionTable()
   {
      Question q1 = new Question(1,"Example Question?","Yes","Sometimes","No");
      addQuestion(q1);
   }

   private void addQuestion (Question question)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(QUESTION_NUMBER, question.getQuestionNum());
      cv.put(QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
      cv.put(ANSWER_ONE, question.getOption1());
      cv.put(ANSWER_TWO, question.getOption2());
      cv.put(ANSWER_THREE, question.getOption3());
      db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
   }

}
```

This is the activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
   Button screenOneButton;
   Button screenTwoButton;
   Button screenThreeButton;
   Button quitButton;
   DatabaseHelper mydb;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}
```

This is programmed under Intellij software and was able to open the database under DB SQL software FYI!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inserting val manually into SQLite database you have to use `addQuestion()` method in `DatabaseHelper` class to insert val into the table.

You add only one question. Call `addQuestion()` from `onCreate()` method after the call to `fillQuestionTable()` method.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Questions.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Questions";
    public static final String QUESTION_NUMBER = "Question_Number";
    public static final String QUESTION = "Question";
    public static final String ANSWER_ONE = "Answer_ONE";
    public static final String ANSWER_TWO = "Answer_THREE";
    public static final String ANSWER_THREE = "Answer_FOUR";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Constructor for DatabaseHelper
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // Create database table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;
        final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                QUESTION_NUMBER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
                ANSWER_ONE + " TEXT, " +
                ANSWER_TWO + " TEXT, " +
                ANSWER_THREE + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);

        // Fill the database table with questions
        fillQuestionTable();
    }

    // Upgrade database table if version changes
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Fill database table with example question
    private void fillQuestionTable() {
        Question q1 = new Question(1,"Example Question?","Yes","Sometimes","No");
        addQuestion(q1);
    }

    // Add question to database table
    private void addQuestion (Question question) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(QUESTION_NUMBER, question.getQuestionNum());
        cv.put(QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
        cv.put(ANSWER_ONE, question.getOption1());
        cv.put(ANSWER_TWO, question.getOption2());
        cv.put(ANSWER_THREE, question.getOption3());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }
}
```

---

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button screenOneButton;
    Button screenTwoButton;
    Button screenThreeButton;
    Button quitButton;
    DatabaseHelper mydb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create instance of DatabaseHelper
        DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    }
}
```

---

You created the `database` with the columns, but you didn't add values to it, you add them manually using SQL insert statements.

This works for me:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(QUESTION_NUMBER, 1);
contentValues.put(QUESTION, "Example Question?");
contentValues.put(ANSWER_ONE, "Yes");
contentValues.put(ANSWER_TWO, "Sometimes");
contentValues.put(ANSWER_THREE, "No");
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

Modify the values according to your needs and make sure to call the table in `onCreate()` method.

---

You are creating new instance of `DatabaseHelper` inside `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity`.

This worked for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button screenOneButton;
    Button screenTwoButton;
    Button screenThreeButton;
    Button quitButton;
    DatabaseHelper mydb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    }
}
```

Access the `mydb` instance throughout your 'MainActivity' class.